# Job sheduler to be used across multiple web applications

Tags: asp.net-core, scheduled-tasks, quartz.net, hangfire

I have multiple web applications (.NET Core 3.1) that need to utilize one resource (another, third-party, legacy application) via it's API. The servers are really terrible and I can only make only few concurrent request and the same time (assume I can't change that).

I'm looking for some scheduler that can be used across all applications to manage requests made to that legacy application.

For now each application uses it's own Quartz .Net instance for different maintenance purposes. From what I know there is no way in which I can "chain" does instances so that only certain number of request will be made to that API at the same time across multiple Quartz schedulers (correct me if I'm wrong).

I was looking at Hangfire for answers but I don't think it is possible as well. According to [this github extension](https://github.com/GeXiaoguo/Hangfire.MAMQSqlExtension) I can actually create one Hangfire server that will be used by multiple applications, each one utilizing different queue but from what I can gather I cannot limit the number of workers per queue to control the number of requests made in total.

Any ideas?

Comment: What if you build a kind of proxy for the legacy API as a normal .NET Core application (no background processes, just controller methods and calls to the legacy API).  This application can do a centralist queuing (maybe caching and other functions as well?) for all of your applications. Your other application than using your "proxy" in their background processes without the need for synchronization?

Comment: Yeah sure, that was my backup plan to create some web app with transnational outbox pattern. But when you think about it there are two/three downsides to this approach: 1. With Quartz/Hangfire I can monitor all of my jobs in one place per application (in hangfire I get an extra neat little interface for it) 2. I get an additional app to worry about in terms of supporting it. 3. If I there would be a need to create next app that utilities that api I need to modify proxy whereas in solutions such as hangfire/Quartz the job definitions are provided within each app separately

Comment: I agree, but sometimes starting simple (with drawbacks) and evolves can be a suitable approach. However, another thought: **RemoteSemaphore**. We could rephrase your problem as a synchronization problem. Multiple processes try to interact with a constraint single resource. If you had this problem within a process, you would use something like [SemaphoreSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim) to synchronize your concurrent request and ensure that the resource is only used as often concurrently as the max counter of the SemaphoreSlim.

Comment: With a RemoteSemaphore each job inside each of your services would request a RemoteSemaphore. Only if granted, they proceeded; otherwise, they are waiting until it's their turn. This *could* be done by modifying the JobScheduler and adding a central component acting as this RemoteSemaphore

Comment: This actually is a pretty good idea (i mean named system semaphores). I was hoping for something more "elegant", I suppose, considering that all of the apps need to run on the same server for this approach to work. However in my case of relatively not resource-intensive intranet apps this could do the trick. I'm gonna wait for other suggestions (if any). In the meantime I'm gonna think about your proposal more. Thanks!